# Как правильно вернуть массив из метода?

Tags: java

Есть метод, который делает положительные числа отрицательными и наоборот.

```
public static int[] invert(int[] array) {
    for (int i : array) {
        i *= -1;
    }
    return array;
}
```

При попытке возврата, мне кидает значение

```
[I@15db9742
```

Как правильно сделать, что бы все работало?
p.s. Задача с codewars [*тык*](https://www.codewars.com/kata/invert-values/train/java)

Comment: так а откуда вы получаете такое значение? array.toString? )

Comment: Все, разобрался. Я получал ссылку на объект массива в памяти, а мне нужно было вывести в консоль содержимое массива.

Comment: По заданию, вам ничего не надо выводить в консоль. Нужно вернуть исправленный массив

Answer (score 0):

Не менял вашу идею решения, немного подправил.

```
 for (int i=0; i<array.length;i++) {
        array[i]*=-1;
    System.out.println(array[i]);
    }

    return array;

  }
```

Comment: Не подскажите почему второй вариант сработал, в отличии от foreach?

Comment: @Thisisqwi потому что форич не изменяет текущий array. Он просто предоставляет значения

Comment: @Thisisqwi, а вам надо изменять элементы массива, а не выводить их

Comment: Не вижу  смысла в возврате массива, так как обхект вы будете и так менять по ссылке, то есть этот метод можно сделать void и пользоваться дальше тем массивом, который закинули в метод

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov там метод статический, посмотрите на само задание по ссылке. Ну, и как я написал, логику работы приложения придуманную автором я не менял.

Comment: @dred, то что метод статический роли не играет, но то, что вы не меняли код  пользователя согласен, просто нет смысла отдельно выносить это замечание ответом, написал к вашему.